# Changing Language Programmatically Inside a ViewPager

Tags: android, android-viewpager

Apparently switching tabs in a ViewPager changes the language chosen using `Locale.setDefault` and `getActivity().getResources().updateConfiguration`.
I've fixed the rotation in the manifest with `android:screenOrientation="portrait"` and I've managed to call a method of mine everytime each tab is selected(using `OnPageChangeListener`).
I've also used the ViewPager `setOffscreenPageLimit` method to avoid the subsequent calls to `onCreateView` of any tab(6 tabs and `setOffscreenPageLimit(5)`) . After the first `onCreateView`(at app start or after popBackStacks till the fragment under the viewpager container is the first) the language of the views of the left 3 tabs(not the others) is correct but after moving a while it changes back to the device default.
I'm on android 6.0.
This is the languge change

```
Locale.setDefault(selectedLocale);
config.locale = selectedLocale;
getActivity().getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, getActivity().getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
getActivity().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, getActivity().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
```

I'm refreshing the viewpager fragments with

```
while (fm.getBackStackEntryCount()>1) {
            fm.popBackStackImmediate();
        }
        fm.executePendingTransactions();

        ViewPagerContainer fragment = new ViewPagerContainer ();
        fm.beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.pages_container, fragment, ViewPagerContainer .TAG)
                    .addToBackStack("ViewPagerContainer")
                    .commit();
```

Comment: Where do you set `Locale.setDefault(selectedLocale);`?

Comment: In `onCreateView`(using saved shared preferences) and in the listener of the spinner of the fragment that lets the user set the language; then in `onConfigurationChanged` and `onCreate`(again from preferences) of a class that extends application.

Comment: It's also set using the method of class LocaleHelper from [link](https://gunhansancar.com/change-language-programmatically-in-android/). At the best of my tries `Locale.getDefault().getLanguage()` gives what i set before and after `Locale.setDefault(selectedLocale)` but the behavior is erratic.

Comment: Did you check your `SharedPreferences` if you are getting the correct language in `onCreateView`?

Comment: Yes. Anyway setting `setOffscreenPageLimit` the `onCreateView` is called just once for each `ViewPager`'s fragment.

Comment: You should set `setOffScreenPageLimit` only once in your `Activity` of your `ViewPager` that holds your fragments. Not once in each fragment.

Comment: Providing more code will make it easier to answer your question.